# problem rising events with keyboard clicks in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, keyboard-events, pysimplegui

I tried to find codes online about rising events in my PySimpleGUI program by simple keyboard clicks like `ENTER` or `Ctrl+A` for instance but I couldn't just find any about it, I went to the documentation of PySimpleGUI and didn't shut my tap without learning a thing.

Here is a simple code i wrote:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.I(key='In'), sg.B('Ok')],[sg.T(enable_events=True,key='T')]]

win=sg.Window("Keyboard Events", layout)

while True:
    event, value= win.read()
    #close event
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    #greeting evnt
    if event in ('Ok'): #( 'OK', 'KEYBOARD ENTER EVENT'):
        msg = "Hello "+value['In']  # message to show user
        win['T'].update(msg)        # show user message
        win['In'].update("")        # clear input field after submitting

win.close()
```

What should I say to PySimpleGUI for let it run `#greeting event` when I press the `ENTER` key? Can someone help me please? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question!  And yes, its the documentation, not you.  While this may not answer your question directly, here is some useful information.

You can choose to set `return_keyboard_events=True` as option when creating the window (`sg.Window()`).  This will return every key hitting an input, as well as some scrolling events, meta keys, and so on.

`window.read()` returns a tuple `(event, values)`.  `event` can be:

- None (`sg.WIN_CLOSED`)
- A string of length one with the key from an input.  For example 'a'.
- The key of a control.  For example, 'Ok'.
- A tuple with more information.  For example, clicking in a table gives a tuple of `(keyname, "+CLICKED+", (row, column)`
- A special key, such as `Return:6033979789` or `Meta_L:922810622`.

I use this as an alternative to `bind_return_key` when I might have multiple text entries on the screen:

```
    if isinstance(event, str) and event.startswith('Return'):
       event = 'return ' + self.window.find_element_with_focus().key
```

Also, I find printing to the console is necessary to debug events:

```
event, values = self.window.read()
print(f" event (type:{type(ui_event)}, {ui_event}, len:({len(ui_event)})"
      f" with values {ui_values}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Option required for element

- `sg.Input(do_not_clear=False, key='In')` clear input field after event
- `sg.Button('Ok', bind_return_key=True)` the return key will cause this button to be pressed

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.I(do_not_clear=False, key='In'), sg.B('Ok', bind_return_key=True)],[sg.T(enable_events=True,key='T')]]

win=sg.Window("Keyboard Events", layout)

while True:
    event, value= win.read()
    #close event
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    #greeting evnt
    if event == 'Ok':
        msg = "Hello "+value['In']  # message to show user
        win['T'].update(msg)        # show user message

win.close()
```